# Apache Cordova 6.1.0. cordova-lib@undefined

Tags: cordova

I update to latest Apache Cordova 6.1.0 version with

`npm install -g cordova`

but when i use command

`cordova -v`

Command Prompt output

`cordova 6.1.0 (cordova-lib@undefined)`

Why it happens and how to fix this?

I use Windows 8.

I posted on StackOverflow because I not found feedback on the official website Cordova.

#### Edit:

This issue is fixed in cordova 6.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an open issue. Please follow [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/859) issue thread to stay updated, and BTW it isn't causing any problem to me using cordova utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

**npm remove -g cordova**

**npm install -g cordova@6.0.x**

Comment: downgrading will cause npm warning `npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and now out of date with respect to npm.`